# /etc/profile.d/sh.local

Tags: centos, rhel, profile

I am trying to delete/remove `/etc/profile.d/sh.local` (not using it and a security scan flags it) from the system when the system is built but, it is not working. I thought `/etc/profile.d/sh.local` is created from `/etc/profile` (snippet of `/etc/profile`):

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

I created a new `/etc/profile` by removing the section for `/etc/profile.d/sh.local` from `/etc/profile` and build a new server without a `sh.local` section but when I login I still see `/etc/profile.d/sh.local`.

Obviously this file gets created by other processes that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/profile.d/sh.local` is shipped in the `setup` package, it’s not created by another script. You can delete it.

The `/etc/profile` snippet you quote takes care of sourcing `sh.local` if it exists; it doesn’t create it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarifications.